# How do I resurrect Rahgot?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I think I did it with Krosis and it works fine.

I can't do this with Rahgot

First I did

```
prid 0007E4B9
moveto player
enable
resurrect 1
```

He is nowhere to be seen.

With krosis, I did

```
prid 000F8A48
moveto player
enable
resurrect 1
```

and it works. Well, I tried that again and it's no longer work. So I wonder if the location is important or anything. Given that I am using refid instead of baseid, it's the same krosis I got in searpoint and yet he had his masks and staffs. Why I can't do the same on Rahgot?

What am I missing?

I want to get that last mask that I think I've lost. I will just summon a copy of the mask myself, but I will try this first.

Comment: You really should try. I added the mask anyway. But kind of strange that I can kill Krosis but not Rahgot. In any case, even with the best of care, I lost two masks somehow. What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Rahgot is one of the few dragon priests that respawns, he might be the only one [Volsung may, I can't remember].

If you kill Rahgot a second time, his ash pile will not contain the mask if you took it the first time. The only thing to do would be to use a console hack.